# xterm cursor not inverting properly with highlighted / reverse text

Tags: ubuntu, xterm, cursor

When opening an `xterm` on my Ubuntu 16.04.1 system, the cursor disappears whenever it's moved over highlighted / reversed text. It remains the same color as the foreground and completely blocks out the character it's on top of.

On my CentOS 7 system which comes with a slightly older version of `xterm` (295 vs 322 on Ubuntu), the cursor color inverts properly (see the following screenshot):

[image: see this for examples]

So far I've noticed this happening in `alpine` and `vim`; in `bash`/`tcsh` the cursor seems to work fine. The built-in terminal app and `urxvt` do not exhibit this problem at all. Any ideas on what might be causing this?

Comment: There was a fix in [patch #311 (see link)](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_311) which might not be complete.

Comment: I've just reproduced this on 325.

Comment: Ah, interesting. Is it safe to conclude this is a bug then? If so, looking forward to the patch :P

Comment: presumably fixed in patch #328.  CentOS 7 has #329.   Ubuntu 16 has #322.  Debian 9 has #327, Debian testing has #331.  Ubuntu 18 will have #330.