# xterm cursor hides character in reverse video mode

Tags: debian, colors, xterm

How can I prevent xterm version 327-2 (on Debian testing) from hiding the character in reverse video mode?

For example, if I run

```
xterm -geometry 20x2 -e /bin/sh -c "echo -ne '\033[0;7mtesting\033[0m\033[Gfoo'; sleep 999"
```

, then I get the following bad output (the letter *t* is hidden by the cursor):

[image: xterm reverse video bad and good output]

In the bad output above the cursor above the reverse-video letter t is making it invisible. In the good output above the letter t is visible in normal colors (reverse of reverse). How can I make xterm 327-2 give me the good output?

I was trying to set the cursorColor, highlightColor, highlightColorMode, highlightReverse, highlightTextColor resources of xterm to various empty, true and false values. They made a difference,  but nothing helped: the letter t never showed up if it was under the cursor in reverse video.

Some other software I tried:

- xterm and rxvt in 1995: good
- xterm 256: good
- xterm 297: good
- xterm 327-2: **BAD**
- gnome-terminal 2.30.2: good (also the cursor is blinking between normal and reverse video)
- gnome-terminal 3.22.2: good (also the cursor is blinking between normal and reverse video)
- rxvt 2.7.10: good

Comment: This has been asked before, at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332903/ .

Comment: Agreed: seems to have been fixed in [xterm #328][(https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_328), mid-2017.  I don't know about **1995**.

Answer (score 1):

You might be talking about this item mentioned in the changes for [patch #328:](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_328)

> improve fix for Debian #759734, addressing a case where non-colored cursor would be invisible against reverse-video (see patch #311).